# How to get values from a Stripe\Collection JSON output

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm working with `Stripe` in a `PHP` app. I've created a product and set prices for it via code. I added `'lookup_key' => value` to each price. That all worked. When I use stripes `lookup_keys` command to get prices by that key, I do not know how to parse the output returned.

Example price:

```
$stripe->prices->create([
   'product' => $product['id'],
   'unit_amount' => 35000,
   'currency' => 'usd',
   'lookup_key' => 'double'
 ]);
```

To get the price for the `lookup_key => double`, I use:

```
$double = $stripe->prices->all(['lookup_keys' => ['double'] ]);

var_dump($double );
```

The output for that is:

```
Stripe\Collection JSON: {
  "object": "list",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "price_1OeHBECDQQBHRZz868I26QUy",
      "object": "price",
      "active": true,
      "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
      "created": 1706620608,
      "currency": "usd",
      "custom_unit_amount": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "lookup_key": "double",
      "metadata": [],
      "nickname": null,
      "product": "prod_PTDcNZpXM6NJMd",
      "recurring": null,
      "tax_behavior": "unspecified",
      "tiers_mode": null,
      "transform_quantity": null,
      "type": "one_time",
      "unit_amount": 35000,
      "unit_amount_decimal": "35000"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "url": "/v1/prices"
}"
```

How do I parse this to get the `"unit_amount": 35000`, or other items?  OR, is there an easier way to get a price or prices from a product.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I've formatted your JSON. Fundamentally, something like `$double->data[0]->unit_amount` will do the trick.

Comment: [How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-to-extract-and-access-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$unitAmount = $double->data[0]->unit_amount;